# GetProperties cannot be made generic in Linq statement

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following code:

```
public static IList<SortOption> SortValues()
{
var sortValues = (from prop in typeof(SolrSchemaApp1).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
  where Attribute.IsDefined(prop, typeof(SolrSortAttribute)) 
  select new SortOption(prop.Name)).ToList();
return sortValues;
}
```

where SolrSchemaApp1 is a class derived from an interface called ISolrDocument.

I want to pass in an instance of SolrSchemaApp2 and make my code select the sort properties from that one instead of SolrSchemaApp1. In effect, I want to do this:

```
public static IList<SortOption> SortValues(ISolrDocument schemaToScan)
{
var sortValues = (from prop in typeof(schemaToScan).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
  where Attribute.IsDefined(prop, typeof(SolrSortAttribute))
  select new SortOption(prop.Name)).ToList();
return sortValues;
}
```

All I have done is replaced the hard coded SolrSchemaApp1 with a variable of a different type. However, I get the error

**The type or namespace name 'schemaToScan' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**

I'm struggling with the syntax of using GetProperties on an arbitrary class.

How do I use Linq to scan the properties of the class that I pass in as a parameter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
replace typeof(schemaToScan)
```

by

```
schemaToScan.GetType()
```

schemaToScan is an instance of a type, not a type.

Answer (score 1):

`schemaToScan` is not a *type* (it is a *parameter*), so `typeof(schemaToScan)` makes no sense. You have 3 options, all of which have slightly different meanings:

1: hard-code to `typeof(ISolrDocument)` if the property is on the `interface`

2: use `schemaToScan.GetType()` if the property is on the concrete type of the implementing object

3: make it a generic method, and use `typeof(T)` if the property is on the declared type of the **variable** (not object) being passed:

```
    public static IList<SortOption> SortValues<T>(T schemaToScan)
        where T : ISolrDocument
    { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, use `schemaToScan.GetType()` instead of `typeof(schemaToScan)` -- `typeof` is used to get the `Type` for a type name.  Use `GetType()` for getting the `Type` of an instance.